# Broke Meteor by creating a collections 'accounts'

Tags: meteor, accounts

I accidentally created a collection `accounts` ... yes I know I wasn't thinking;
it was really dumb of me. But now my Meteor installation is broken completely.
for code like `Accounts.createUser` server hangs and returns error 'method createUser undefined.'
OS is windows10

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Meteor, removed and re-added `accounts-..` nothing works. and of course the collection is no long 'accounts'
Please help if you might have an idea how to resolve this..

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove all your accounts collection code (assume you have done that already)
2. Stop your server
3. Run meteor reset (from the command line in your project directory where you run meteor)
4. Restart your server

That should do it.

Comment: I have tried that too; i still get error : "method createUser is not defined"

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem like that would be related to having a mongo collection named Accounts then. Do you have anything else defined as Accounts in your code?

Comment: Yeah .. sorry I found the problem ..me.. again :-) hhhh. The error was in the hook `Accounts.onCreateUser`. I tried calling `Accounts.createUser(user);` again inside `Accounts.onCreateUser` to bypass the problem of new users being stored in temp storage until the 2nd accounts.createUser...